# Breaking Luks encryption from a Memory Dump

Tags: linux, lvm, encryption, disk, luks

I lost my LUKS encryption passphrase and I know that there are ways to recover the disk from a memory dump so I used the post of [Subash SN](https://blog.appsecco.com/breaking-full-disk-encryption-from-a-memory-dump-5a868c4fc81e)

I used findaes to extract the keys from the dump:

```
Searching snapshot.raw
Found AES-128 key schedule at offset 0x2ab8b02b:
99 d4 7b 6a d0 44 9a 51 cc bf 5d f1 3c f7 12 0f
Found AES-128 key schedule at offset 0x2d456d0d:
de 84 11 39 06 a1 de 36 66 72 55 38 31 d2 84 13
Found AES-256 key schedule at offset 0x330716ff:
79 8a 00 0f 0c 17 9e b8 97 4e 91 92 5b c3 ae ac 2c 8f bf 8d 67 98 60 03 f5 0b e6 11 cc 77 60 d4
Found AES-256 key schedule at offset 0x33071eff:
72 98 38 ae c8 d5 89 5e b0 7a 57 75 74 ec 6f 9e 5b 4d 30 c1 cb fd 51 59 1f 93 a1 30 92 1f 24 8d
```

I'm using SystemRescueCD and mounted the disk, output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cf378c8

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 209713151 208711682 99.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 209713151 208711680 99.5G 83 Linux
```

The next step was to find the size of the encrypted partition which is `/dev/sda5`.:

```
blockdev --getsz /dev/sda5
208711680
```

The next step is to unlock and decrypt the partition:

```
echo "0 <size> crypt aes-xts-plain64 <key> 0 </dev/drive> 4096" | sudo dmsetup create luks-volume
```

I use it as followed:

```
echo "0 208711680 crypt aes-xts-plain64 798a000f0c179eb8974e91925bc3aeac2c8fbf8d67986003f50be611cc7760d4729838aec8d5895eb07a577574ec6f9e5b4d30c1cbfd51591f93a130921f248d 0 /dev/sda5 4096" | dmestup create luks-volume.
```

I did not get any errors nor warnings. But if I use `lsblk` i'm unable to see the LVM partitions.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cf378c8

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 209713151 208711682 99.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 209713151 208711680 99.5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-volume: 99.5 GiB, 106843602944 bytes, 208678912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5` could help, if you have LUKS2 the `4096` `offset` wouldn't be enough, default metadata size for LUKS2 is 16 MiB (32768 sectors). Also check what system actually sees on the DM device (e.g. using `blkid -p /dev/mapper/luks-volume`)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what this memory dump is and why it should hold a copy of your key. Was the drive unlocked when you realised you'd list the key? Did you then unplug it (lock it) to try the memory dump?

Comment: This won't help the question but 208711680-4096=208707584 so the command should start with `echo "0 208707584 crypt `. Assuming 4096 is correct (cryptsetup luksDump would tell it)

Comment: @A.B yeah there feels like a mismatch between the OPs problem and the article referenced. I understand well enough what the article is about.  But it seems security related and unrelated to recovering lost keys. Perhaps there's just a big gap in the information in the question.  But what's really important here is how the OP went about getting the snapshot making it clear why they believe the (unencrypted) key might be in it.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny, thanks for your help. The default metadata size of 16 MiB worked and was able to decrypt it. Where can I find the default metadata size of luks2? Do you have a reference?

Comment: AS VojtechTrefny already wrote: `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5` gives this information. You can't trust default. Also the tutorial has an error: you should substract this header size from the overal size of the dm mapping, as I wrote previously (except it's now 32768)

Comment: using xxd -r -p + cryptsetup --master-key-file would also avoid the need to use dmsetup and know this value.

Comment: @A.B If I use cryptosetup luksDump /dev/sda5 i get this error "Unsupported LUKS version 2".

Comment: That means your cryptsetup tool must be upgraded to a newer version

Comment: @A.B What do you mean with "using xxd -r -p + cryptsetup --master-key-file "? Could you elaborate this?

Comment: @A.B Yes, I'm now using the latest stable version of Systemrescuecd which supports it now. I checkt he man page of cryptsetup but this is What I saw "Use a master key stored in a file."

Comment: Elaboration: You have the master key in hex format. You use xxd to store it in binary format in a file and use it with --master-key-file.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the elaboration. But what's the difference between using the hex format which I use instead of the binary?

Comment: none. But there's no other option than --master-key-file to accept directly hex. with some bash shell construct ( `<()` ) it's probably possible to not really use a file.

Comment: @A.B But it's pssobile to decrypt the luks with the following method: "echo "0 208678912 crypt aes-xts-plain64 <masterkey>  0 /dev/sda5 32768" | dmsetup create luks-volume. Thats why i'm lost why I should create a binary if this is also working.

Comment: 32768 <--- you didn't have this value and it didn't work. cryptsetup doesn't require this value, it retrieves it.

Comment: @A.B Aha! Ok, I will test try that also. Thx for the explanation and sorry for the misunderstanding